# jQuery - Droppable doesn't accept more than one draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, droppable

I have *n* draggable elements, all to be collected in one droppable div, say "#collector".

Can anybody explain me why "#collector" doesn't accept more than one draggable element in it?
The counter stops at "1". Here's the code:

```
$("#argh").draggable();
$("#argh2").draggable();

var i = 1;

$("#collector").droppable({
    drop: 
         function( event, ui ) {
           $(this).addClass("fill").find("p").html("There are "+i+"/10 elements.");
           i++;
         }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, the droppable is accepting multiple draggable.

Here is the working [jsFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrpruthvi/P9hCu/1/)

```
$("#collector").droppable({
drop: 
     function( event, ui ) {
       $(this).addClass("fill").find("p").html("There are "+i+"/10 elements.");
       i++;
     }
});
```

If you still find it difficult to drop multiple div's then try including the **tolerance** option for the droppable div. Refer [API DOC.](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-tolerance)

Comment: Thanks. I found out that the reason why it wasn't working was that the droppable area was declared in a bigger function which contains it. Now it perfecty works, the problem simply was somewhere else. :)